# How do I browse Nokia Lumia 610 files?

Tags: mtp, nokia

Nokia Lumia 610 gets mounted but when I try to open the internal storage, it shows the following message:

> Sorry, could not display all the contents of “Storage”: libmtp error:  could not get object handles.

Installing `libmtp` or `mtp` applications from Ubuntu Software Center is not solving the problem.

Comment: Which libmtp or mtp applications did you install?

Comment: I installed gMTP from Ubuntu Software Center and libmtp 1.1.0 from sourceforge

Comment: Possible related Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/1247572

Comment: Clausi... This is about Windows Phone 7.8. Lumia 620 has Windows 8 OS. I am having problems with Lumia 610

Comment: which ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Its Ubuntu 13.10 Linux 3.11.0-15-generic

Comment: go to the nokia support website and chat with the official,they could possibly help.

Comment: They can't..now the only way seems to be a Zune alternative on Ubuntu. And I can't see that coming. Best thing would be to throw away Windows Phone and switch to Android.

Comment: I read your comment that zune does not work with wine.have you read <http://www.ehow.com/how_7317935_use-zune-ubuntu.html>

Comment: MTP devices should work right out of the box with 13.04 and onward. Looks like an issue with libmtp, please have a look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/417323/my-mtp-capable-device-is-not-detected-what-can-i-do-about-that

Comment: I would search for any gui application that lets you handle windows phones. Maybe you can find something else on Lumia's forum. You could also try Daniel's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a fresh Ubuntu install and without installing any gtmp, mtp, libmtp tools, I was able to access storage and browse pictures. But not anything else. In a Lumia 610 either work with Skydrive or try using bluetooth transfer application for mp3, mp4 files. 
There is no other way, unless we get a Zune software for Ubuntu.

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by "anything else"? Since 14.04 I can access the storage and SD card of my Lumia *620* just fine. **Learn to address your issues, or things will never get fixed.** A Zune software for Linux/Ubuntu from Microsoft that does nothing else than talk to the device via MTP will not happen, you can give your hopes up on that.

Answer (score 2):

try to install gmtp from the Ubuntu Software center. It worked for my windows phone.

Comment: Which windows phone do you have..??

Comment: Sorry for beign late, HTC Mozart

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be exactly what you are looking for, but this was my solution to a similar problem; I've always had problems getting media devices to work with ubuntu via usb. My solution is to set up an ftp server on the phone/device and then use a good ftp client like FileZilla on your computer to access it. If you have a wlan at home then this works great out of the box. I don't know anything about Windows phones, but I'd be willing to bet there's an ftp sever app out there somewhere. It's actually easier sometimes to to it this way, no messing with wires, etc. I hope this helps.