# Zune alternatives

Tags: alternative

Are there any Zune ( http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/zune-software ) alternatives available for ubuntu ( or any linux distro ) that seem reliable for a windows phone?

I managed to talk in my girlfriend to switch from windows to ubuntu and she seems to enjoy this distro a lot but the only thing she misses is this Zune software for her windows phone.

I tried to install Virtualbox w/ windows 7 + guest additions and extension pack as well, but her phone couldn't get recognized by Zune inside virtualbox ( windows 7 ).

The only idea I have left is to install ubuntu alongside windows ( dual - boot ) but I believe that any alternative would be a better solution to this problem ( since dual-boot would require constant restart between the two OS and it is kinda annoying ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably something like [Banshee](http://banshee.fm/), [Amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/), [Clementine](http://www.clementine-player.org/) or you can use Ubuntu's default media player Rythmbox. If you decide to go with Banshee (which is the one I use), make sure that the MTP extension is enabled go to Edit --> Preferences --> Extensions --> Device support --> MTP Media player support.

Comment: I'll try it out...Since you are a Banshee user, do you find this program suitable for your purposes? And will Banshee fully support the interaction "computer-mobile phone" and vice versa? The only reason she misses Zune is because that was the only program she used so far to download and upload music to her phone and since I am an android user, I'm not familiar with windows phone and I don't want to cause any troubles on her phone ( like deleting all data )...So, Banshee should work with windows phone?

Comment: It works fine for my wife, and what she does with it.  You may want to take a look at this [article](http://lifehacker.com/5930512/how-can-i-make-all-my-desktop-and-mobile-operating-systems-play-well-together)..

Answer (score 0):

I found that Windows (8.1) running in VirtualBox is very picky to detect a connected Windows Phone. It sometimes involves a reboot, reset (ouch!), shutting down the VM, reconnecting the device to the VM or actually replugging the device. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

No...the alternative to Zune is not in sight yet...and Wine could not install it.
No mtp or libmtp tools would fix the problem. Trust me..I have a Lumia 610 with Windows 7.8.
Your best shot is..dual booting Windows with Ubuntu.
If you have Windows Phone 8, then you probably don't need a Zune Software.
I feel to share my disappointment [How do I browse Nokia Lumia 610 files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399581/how-do-i-browse-nokia-lumia-610-files)